# Can i run Android 2.0 application in Android 1.5?

Tags: android

I developed one simple android application targeting the Mobiles with android 2.0 OS.I want to know whether i can run the same application in android 1.5 .If any body knows it please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file (located in the base of the project) there's a tag called uses-sdk

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="5" />
```

Those numbers are known as API level where 3 is for Android 1.5 and 5 is for Android 2.0.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Note that this allows you to compile your code against the 2.0 SDK but if you use classes or functionality in your app that is not supported in 1.5 then it will crash. I recommend that you create an AVD for 1.5 and 1.6 for testing.

You may want to consider just compiling against 1.5 for simplicty.

Lastly, a common trick is to compile against 2.0 and avoid/disable features that aren't supported in earlier versions of android the following article shows how do this.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html

Comment: Lastly, you'll want to use the lowest API version that will support your app so that you can target the largest audience. Here's a graph showing the spread of android installs based on market activity. http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply.The Simple application that i have created is a Bluetooth application.Only Android 2.0 Version contains the Bluetooth api.So i created the application in android 2.0.But now my target device is Android 1.5 .Is it possible to run that application in android 1.5.because android 1.5 version also contains the bluetooth capability.

Comment: No you can't, because 1.5 does not have the APIs you are using.

Comment: I developed an App aimed at version 3 and am implementing some v5 things. Any idea when I added this line and increased the target API that all my view's heights halved?